# Получение статистики другого сайта и отправка их посредством JS

Tags: php, javascript

Приветствую.

Хочу собрать статистику по сайту через встраиваемый код такого типа:

```
<script>
(function(w, d, s, u, id) {
    var js = d.createElement(s); js.async = 1; js.src = u; var js2 = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; js2.parentNode.insertBefore(js, js2); window.ProjectId = id;
})(window, document, 'script', 'js/module-visit.js', '1358');
</script>
```

Что нужно написать в module-visit.js, чтобы данные принимались и отправлялись в php-файл для дальнейшей записи?

Comment: За что минус, не понял?

Comment: Ваш скрипт делает сейчас немногим больше `<script src="js/module-visit.js"></script>`

> Что нужно написать в module-visit.js, чтобы данные принимались и отправлялись в php-файл для дальнейшей записи?

Какие данные? Написать, очевидно, что-нибудь c ajax.

Минус за "работа за автора".

Comment: Например, считать посетителей, присваивать им id в куку, анализировать строчку и находить utm метки, если они имеются...

Comment: ну да, вот это и напишите в module-visit.js , 

ваш вопрос напоминает мужика с погнутым рулем, который хочет, чтобы ему машину починили.

Answer (score 1):

Такие махинации антивирь может выдать как подозрение, а вообще парсите сайт, раз надо что-то делать.